# CodeIgniter maintain datat throught controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a main menu in my application, it loads depending on the role of the user that I validate from a table in my data base, but I have to recreate this menu everytime I call a new controller, here is the way I'm doing it:

User Controller:

```
class User extends Ci_Controller {

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

        if (!$this->session->userdata('session_user')) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("mensaje", 'No cuenta con permisos *');
            redirect();
            $this->session_usuario = 1;
        }

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('session_user');
        $image        = $session_data['img'];
        $nickname     = $session_data['nick'];
        $res          = "";

        $this->layout->setLayout('layout/admin');
        $this->layout->setImage(base_url().$image);
        $this->layout->setNick($nickname);

        $data['module'] = $this->usuarios_model->seleccionarModulos($session_data['perfil'] );

        for ($i=0; $i < count($data['module']) ; $i++) {                                                    
            $info['functionality'] = $this->usuarios_model->seleccionarFuncionalidades(     $session_data['usuario'], $data['module'][$i]['id']);
            $data['module'][$i]['route'] = $this->load->view($data['module'][$i]['route'], $info, true);
        }

        foreach ($data['module'] as $key => $value) { 
            $res .= $value['route']; 
        }     

        $this->layout->setMenu($res);

    }
```

And exactly the same in the Support Controller:

```
class Support extends Ci_Controller {

    private $user; 
    private $permiso; 
    private $order;

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

        if (!$this->session->userdata('session_user')) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("mensaje", 'No cuenta con permisos *');
            redirect();
            $this->session_usuario = 1;
        }

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('session_user');
        $image        = $session_data['img'];
        $nickname     = $session_data['nick'];
        $res          = "";

        $this->layout->setLayout('layout/admin');
        $this->layout->setImage(base_url().$image);
        $this->layout->setNick($nickname);

        $data['module'] = $this->usuarios_model->seleccionarModulos($session_data['perfil'] );

        for ($i=0; $i < count($data['module']) ; $i++) {                                                    
            $info['functionality'] = $this->usuarios_model->seleccionarFuncionalidades(     $session_data['usuario'], $data['module'][$i]['id']);
            $data['module'][$i]['route'] = $this->load->view($data['module'][$i]['route'], $info, true);
        }

        foreach ($data['module'] as $key => $value) { 
            $res .= $value['route']; 
        }     

        $this->layout->setMenu($res);

    }
```

I know that its a wrong way to solve this problem and I want to improve it and reuse the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fast solution is to create a custom controller and have all yours extend that:

Inside the `core` directory create a MY_Controller.php controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    // your common code here
  }
}
```

All your child controllers that need that code:

```
class User extends MY_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
     // this will inherit the MY_Controller constructor
   }
}
```